# ADB connection localhost:(emulator number)

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, localhost, adb, bluestacks

There are some questions I would like to ask you, I would be glad if you help.

1. I just started Flutter vs code, I have to enter adb connection localhost:(emulator number) every time I turn on the computer to recognize the emulator (bluestacks). Is this something I have to do when I turn on computer every time, or did I forget to set it somewhere?
2. adb connection I see it entered as localhost:5555 in most places but when I try 'cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5555: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)' I'm getting the error. I would be glad if you help, I wish you a good day.

I know I need to enter adb connect localhost:(emulator number) when connecting and I provide the connection but I have to do this every time I turn on the computer.

Comment: how related are these two questions? generally when you have multiple questions, you write multiple question posts.